# Using background-image with ngStyle returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I try to add images (using API to load items) as **background-image** of element. But it keeps `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` error. Though it actually renders url. 
Here is the template side:

```
 <div class="col s12 m4" *ngFor="let partner of partners">
                <div class="card" *ngIf='partner'>
                    <div class="card-image " [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + partner?.photo['url'] + ')'}">
                        <a class=" btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light blue left ">
                            <i class="material-icons ">shopping_cart</i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab red " [routerLink]='"/dashboard/partners/edit/"+partner["id"]'>
                            <i class="large material-icons ">mode_edit</i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <h5 class="center font-weight-400 ">{{partner.name}}</h5>
                        <p class="center ">{{partner.category.name}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
  </div>
```

and controller:

```
  export class PartnersListComponent implements OnInit {
    partners: {}[] = [];

    constructor(private _partnersService: PartnersService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this._partnersService.getPartners().subscribe(data => {
        if (data.status == "200") {
          this.partners = data.data;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Example data:

```
category:'',
created_at:"2017-12-27 12:57:50",
deleted_at:null,
first_entry:1,
id:1,
name:"Zara",
photo:{id: 5, url: "example.jpeg"},
updated_at:"2017-12-27 12:57:50",
username:"zara-001"
```

Comment: in your controller make sure the property photo actually exists in your data

Comment: It is the part of data object comes from API

Comment: I understand, but the error says that partner does not have the property photo. check in your ngOnInit and see

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, the `photo` field is not defined for at least one `partner`. You can protect against that situation with the elvis operator:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': `url(${partner?.photo?.url})`}"
```

or

```
[style.background-image]="`url(${partner?.photo?.url})`"
```